# How to force macOS to open https://t..me/ links with correct Telegram client

Tags: launch-services

I have 2 Telegram clients on my MacBook

[image]

^ `/Applications/Telegram.app/Contents/MacOS/Telegram`

[image]

^ `/Applications/Telegram.localized/Telegram.app/Contents/MacOS`

Currently when I click a link, the first one opens.
How to have the second one open instead?

EDIT:
By removing the .app for the first one (Telegram Desktop) from my /Applications folder, links now correctly open in the second one.

However as soon as I restore it, links again open in it.
Even changing the filename and moving it from /Applications to ~/Desktop, macOS still manages to find it when I hit ENTER on a link in Chrome.

[image]

How to prevent this behaviour?

Moreover can anyone shed some light on how macOS is able to track the movement of an app to any location on my filesystem in this manner?

Comment: Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling the first client? That way, the database of protocols updates, so t.me is associated with the 2nd telegram.

Answer (score 4):

t.me page tries to open the URL with `tg://` protocol. You need to change the protocol handler for the same.

See https://superuser.com/questions/548119/how-do-i-configure-custom-url-handlers-on-os-x/548122

In  the following file, find the item with `LSHandlerURLScheme` as `tg` and change its `LSHandlerRole` to what your intended Telegram's Info.plist specifies.

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably changed the protocol handler for `tg://` using SwitftDefaultApps, which can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps/releases), or installed via Homebrew:

```
brew install --cask swiftdefaultappsprefpane
```

Then, simply go into the "URI Schemes" tab, locate `tg://`, and change the viewer to be what you desire. If the application you want does not show up, select "Other", then navigate to the desired app path using the cmd+shift+g shortcut to open the "Go to Folder" feature within the selection window.